# FocalLoss implementation in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

Where can I find a reliable Pytorch implementation of Focal Loss for a multi-class image segmentation problem? I have seen some implementations on GitHub, but I am looking for the official Pytorch version, similar to nn.BCELoss.
If there is no official implementation from Pytorch team, does anyone know a good GitHub implementation that supports different shapes for target and prediction?